# mpdf not working in Google Chrome but working fine in firefox

Tags: php, mpdf

Again am stuck into a situation while creating PDF document usong mPDF. I have done the following code which works fine in Firefox and Safari but not working in Google Chrome.

```
require_once 'mpdf60/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($test, 2);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the result? Have you got any errors in console? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to download pdf or show it in a browser? Probably your problem is that you are not sending proper headers

Comment: @szapio...I am trying to show the PDF in browser...in Firefox its showing but in Chrome its not showing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your comment, try this before you send output:

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $yourFileName . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

require_once 'mpdf60/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($test, 2);
$mpdf->Output();  
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: @szapio...but that will download the filename.pdf....i want to open the PDF in browser

Comment: @szapio...though I have used that code before output still it didn't work

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay can you write here what is the current result in Chrome? How looks response?

Comment: Failed to laod PDF document

Comment: if u wish I can give you the link and you can test it of your own

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay sure, i can look at it

Comment: http://test.multicon.in/test6/index7.php just click on the save as PDF button in the top

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay, something wrong is with your PDF, when i opened it in FF i had a lot of console errors in firebug, probably this is a reason, try to figure out what is a source of those errors

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay i found your problem, problem is, that you output not only pdf but also html, if you save your file you can open it with notepad and check, you got there some html markup `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head> ...` try to not echo/print before you output your pdf, and you can use `ob_clean` function

Comment: where to use ob_clean()

Comment: @szapio...I have removed the <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> ..segment but still its not showing the PDF

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay you didn`t i can still see this markup when i download this pdf, just do not echo site content on your action, and use ob_clean before you send headers and pdf content. Can you paste here your whole code ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i just added the extension with filename inside output function

`$mpdf->Output('myfile.pdf', "D");`

Now it is working in both firefox and chrome.

This is my code:-

`$html = "<h1> Isac Yara </h1>";
 $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
 $mpdf->Output("myfile.pdf", 'D');`