# PDF generated with mPDF not working on android

Tags: php, android, mpdf

I have created website in PHP. I have used one button generate PDF it works perfectly on ipad and desktop but it is not working on android . When I generate PDF on android and I try to open it pdf reader gives error. I tried it with two different pdf reader. Both gives error both shows file format error, file can't be opened. To generate pdf I have used mPDF library.

```
function generatePdf($userData){
$PNG_WEB_DIR = 'phplib/qrcode'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$id = $userData['Id'];
$name = $userData['FirstName'].' '.$userData['LastName'];;
$source =$userData['Source'];
$destination =$userData['Destination'];
$date =$userData['Date'] ;
$FlightName = $userData['FlightName'];
$FlightNumber=$userData['FlightNumber'];
$html .='<div style="text-align: center;">
        <h3 class="form-title">&nbsp;<font size=4>'.$name.'</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <table class="table" style="text-align: left;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="style" >TicketId:</td>
                    <td class="style">'.$id.'</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style">Source:</td>
                    <td class="style">'.$source.'</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style">Destination:</td>
                    <td class="style">'.$destination.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style">Flight Name:</td>
                    <td class="style">'.$FlightName.'</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="style">Flight Number:</td>
                <td class="style">'.$FlightNumber.'</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="style">Date:</td>
                <td class="style">'.$date.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="style">
                <img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.$id.'.png" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>';
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->allow_output_buffering = true;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
//$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->Output('download.pdf','D');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it.Hope that it may help you too. The problem was not with android or desktop. I use firefox on desktop and chrome in android and safari in ios. Code works in safari and firefix but was not working in chrome. This thread helped me.[mpdf not working in Google Chrome but working fine in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451161/mpdf-not-working-in-google-chrome-but-working-fine-in-firefox)

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $yourFileName . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

require_once 'mpdf60/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($test, 2);
$mpdf->Output();  
ob_end_flush();
```

I just changed my code by referring this and it worked.