# I cannot open pdf in chrome created by Mpdf - CodeIgniter . - Failed to load PDF document

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I am new to PHP report generation. I am trying to use MPDF 5.7. When I try create sample pdf using simple php page, it is created successfully. But when I put it in to codeigniter chrome browser says "Failed to load PDF document.". But It can open using firefox. But if i downloaded it, it is not support to open using adobe reader. But still my sample pfd is working well anyway.

This is how I create sample pdf.

```
<?php
$html = '
<h1>mPDF</h1>
<h2>Basic Example Using CSS Styles</h2>
<p class="breadcrumb">Chapter &raquo; Topic</p>
<h3 style="color:red; background-color:gray; margin-left:100px;">Heading 3</h3>';

include("themes/MPDF57/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyleA4.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

When I put it into codeigniter cannot open pdf. my php file is created in 'view' and mpdf library also put in same place in theme folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of opening try to save that first it is working on first instance or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59051722/5289704 This answer may help someone

Answer (score 4):

Your PDF file contains some direct PHP output from your script which makes it corrupt.

It can be a whitespace from after the `?>` PHP closing tag, it can be PHP notice printed during course of generating the file, etc.

Be sure that you disable all layouting your framework provides as it produces the exact same output that could cause this.

---

To troubleshoot further, save your PDF file to disc (`$mpdf->Output('<file path>', "D");`) and open it in a text editor. You will see a bunch of weird characters.

If the file does not start with %PDF-1.4, look for the reason of the output before calling `$mpdf->Output();`.

If there is some readable text at the end of the document, look after calling the `Output` method.

---

I'd suggest you to remove your `?>` PHP closing tag anyway for a good measure.

See also https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/error-messages.html

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is that there are some PHP errors/warnings that show up before the PDF gets written, these make it a non-valid PDF therefore not readable by the Browser.

You can see it by downloading and opening the PDF file with a TextEditor and you'll see PHP errors instead of the standard `%PDF-1.4` value (which should be the first value of the file).

If you suppress warnings `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mpdf->Output('', "I");
```

so then file should be displayed inline in browser instead of downloading it.

if you want to download use `"D"` insted of `"I"`

Comment: I did this. but still problem is not fixed :(

Comment: Check your file saving path may that one is incorrect. please print the file saving path and check

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I didn't notice that header and footer (header was the problem) are still included in my index file. When I called my generate_pdf file it was pulling header and that created error. After I removed header pdf was generated successfully.